# Need to remove all duplicated values in list

Tags: python, arrays, list

I am trying to solve this question "**Good array is the array that does not contain any equal adjacent elements.
Given an integer array A of length N, you are asked to do some operations (possibly zero) to make the
array good. One operation is to remove two equal adjacent elements and concatenate the rest of the array.
A : (1, 2, 2, 3, 4)
An after-one operation : (1, 3, 4)**
" With python list, as follow:

```
L=[]
n=int(input("Enter a num"))
for _ in range(n):
    x=int(input())
    L.append(x)    
print(L)
for z in range(L):
    if L[z]==L[z+1]:
        L.remove(z)
        L.remove(z+1)
print(L)
```

I keep getting this error: Input In [37]
if L[z]==L[z+1]
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
any solutions!!`

Comment: Try this - ```dc = Counter(A);  ans = [x for x, v in dc.items() if v == 1]```  If the inputs is assumedly in the *sorted* order like the OP's example.

Comment: I think a counter-based solution only works if you assume the array is sorted so that identical items are always also adjacent to each other.

Comment: Agreed. It's good observations.  It's purely based on the OP's input... though,

Answer (score 5):

Easiest solution is to `groupby` the array and just keep the groups with only one item:

```
>>> A = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4]
>>> import itertools
>>> A = [i for i, g in itertools.groupby(A) if len(list(g)) == 1]
>>> A
[1, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**
This is NOT correct solution of the above problem. It removes contiguous duplicates from the list. But in question, we need to keep 1 instance of duplicate element.

Please refer to  @funnydman solution. Thanks @funnydman for pointing out the mistake :)

---

You are iterating the list and deleting items from the same :|
Not a good idea!

<s>You can use another list to store the result.</s>

```
result = []
for z in range(len(L)-1):
    if L[z]!=L[z+1]:
        result.append(L[z])
result.append(L[-1])
```

Comment: You need to add `L[-1]` manually to your result list.

Comment: Have you tested your solution? You still add 2 to the list on the third iteration

Comment: Despite not producing the required output, your solution gave me a better thought to solve my problem.. as follows:
L=[]
n=int(input("Enter a num\n"))
for _ in range(n):
    x=int(input("Enter Your List Values: "))
    L.append(x)    
print(L)

result=[]
i=0
while i < len(L) - 1:
        if L[i] != L[i + 1]:
            result.append(L[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            i += 2
result.append(L[-1])
print(result)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Nawal's solution does not produce the correct answer, I would suggest this approach:

```
def get_good_array(alist):
    result = []
    L = alist + [None]
    i = 0
    while i < len(L) - 1:
        if L[i] != L[i + 1]:
            result.append(L[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            i += 2
    return result


assert get_good_array([1, 2, 2, 3, 4]) == [1, 3, 4]
assert get_good_array([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4]) == [3, 4]
assert get_good_array([0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4]) == [0, 3, 4]
assert get_good_array([1, 3, 4, 4]) == [1, 3]
assert get_good_array([1, 3, 4, 4, 5]) == [1, 3, 5]
```

Comment: because i dont want to use a function,
I combined your and Nawal's solution, and I came out with this:
L=[]
n=int(input("Enter a num\n"))
for _ in range(n):
    x=int(input("Enter Your List Values: "))
    L.append(x)    
print(L)

result=[]
i=0
while i < len(L) - 1:
        if L[i] != L[i + 1]:
            result.append(L[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            i += 2
result.append(L[-1])
print(result)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `:` at the end of the if statement, your code should look like the following

```
L=[]
n=int(input("Enter a num"))
for _ in range(n):
    x=int(input())
    L.append(x)    
print(L)
for z in range(L):
    if L[z]==L[z+1]:
        L.remove(z)
        L.remove(z+1)
print(L)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess using `<list>.count()` is quite intuitive approach. As following,

```
def deduplicate(l: list):
    return [value for value in l if l.count(value) == 1]

assert deduplicate([2]) == [2]
assert deduplicate([2, 2]) == []
assert deduplicate([2, 2, 3]) == [3]
assert deduplicate([2, 2, 2]) == []
assert deduplicate([2, 2, 2, 3]) == [3]
```

Comment: OP asks for two adjacent numbers

Comment: Oops, I overlooked it. Thank you for pointing this out!